# Evaluating lambda expression call by value Beta reduction

Tags: lambda-calculus

$ + =  λmnab.m a((n a) b)$
I have to show that $2 + 3     \triangleright_\beta $ 5
what I understand from the lambda expression of + is that it takes 
4 arguments m, n , a , b  But when I have to evaluate $2 + 3$, I only have $2$ arguments 
How do I go about evaluating it.

Comment: When you pass two arguments to a function that expects four arguments, the result is a function that expects the remaining two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the numbers here are [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals):
\begin{align}
2 &= \lambda f.\lambda x. f (f x) \\ 
3 &= \lambda f.\lambda x. f (f (f x))
\end{align}
Applying the first argument (numeral 2) to addition, we get:
$$\begin{split}
& (\lambda m n a b.ma ((na)b))(\lambda fx. f (f x))&~~~~~~~~~\text{($\beta$-reduction)}\\
\to~ & \lambda n a b.((\lambda fx. f (f x))a) ((na)b)
\end{split}$$
Applying the second argument (numeral 3) to the above result, we get:
$$\begin{split}
& \big(\lambda n a b.((\lambda fx. f (f x))a) ((na)b)\big)\bigl(\lambda fx. f(f (f x))\bigr)&~~~~~~~~~\text{($\beta$-reduction)}\\
\to~ & \lambda a b.((\lambda fx. f (f x))a) (((\lambda fx. f(f (f x)))a)b)
\end{split}$$

Comment: thanks. Also is this call-by-value reduction ? I am kind of confused between call by value and call by name

Comment: @Amitwadhwa Yes, it is call-by-value. Say you have an application $e_1\, e_2$. In both reduction strategies you have to first reduce $e_1$ to a lambda expression. Once $e_1$ is reduced to some function, in call-by-name you perform the $\beta$-reduction immediately, while in call-by-value you have to also reduce $e_2$ before doing the $\beta$-reduction. In your exercise though, the arguments are already irreducible (they are functions), so even with call-by-value, the $\beta$-reduction happens immediately.

Comment: @Amitwadhwa If my answer is satisfactory, please consider upvoting it and/or accepting it.

Comment: done. I have one more doubt. In lambda xor = (x (y F T) y). Now I could easily show xor T F = T by writing like (T (F F T) F) = (T T F) = T . But I have to do it using `call by name reduction` could you provide some pointers to it?

Comment: @Amitwadhwa In call-by-name, the reduction would be (T (F F T) F) = (F F T)  = T.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it